# $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{p(x)}{e^x} dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to decide whether the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{p(x)}{e^x} dx$ converges or diverges, when $p(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$?

Comment: Wasn't this just asked here recently?  Pretty sure I at least saw this recently but maybe the question itself was older.

Comment: Found it:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2261008/307169

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use integration by parts and obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{p}{e^x} dx &=& \int_{1}^{\infty} pe^{-x}\,dx\\
 &=& \dfrac{(p+p'+p''+p'''+\cdots)(1)}{e}
\end{eqnarray}